# locate to a folder and execute an application C#

Tags: c#

In my application, the user can select a program:

> `D:/application/app.exe`

I would like to execute it such that the same situation that I have to do on CMD, it will show:

```
C:/
```

then I have to do: D:

then:

```
D:/application/app.exe
```

The application can be only run on its folder for connecting with other libraries.

How can I make it possible to execute it from C# in such a way that it locate to the D:/application first and then execute: app.exe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that they can only run programs from D:\Application ?

Comment: @devn Is a FileOpenDialog (which shows a tree and list of folders and files) an alternative for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [WorkingDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) property of `ProcessStartInfo`. E.g.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
                                       WorkingDirectory = @"D:\application",
                                       FileName = "app.exe"
                                   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the *working directory* when you start a new process:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
{
        FileName = @"D:\application\app.exe",
        WorkingDirectory = @"D:\application",
        //...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) can help you parse and manipulate your input path.

```
Path.GetPathRoot("D:\MyApp\App.exe") --> D:\
Path.GetDirectoryName("D:\MyApp\App.exe") --> D:\MyApp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\application\app.exe") { WorkingDirectory = @"C:\" };
Process.Start(psi);
```